# Firebase js sdk: sendEmailVerification internationalized

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would really like to send internationalized email via [firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk). I know it is possible for the Android Firebase API with [setLanguageCode](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#setLanguageCode(java.lang.String)):

> Sets the user-facing language code for auth operations that can be
>   internationalized, such as sendEmailVerification(). This language code
>   should follow the conventions defined by the IETF in BCP47

However, this function seems not to be present at firebase-js-sdk.
I have tried setting the firebase attribute `languageCode` previous to invoke sendEmailVerification with not success.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

**SOLVED:**

I found the solution based on the info provided at [phone-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

`firebase.auth().languageCode = 'it';`

Comment: can you use Locale to get the language of each user and then pass it through the languageCode ?

Comment: I have tried `firebase.languageCode = locale` and after invoke sendEmailVerification, but the result is always the email send at default language.

Comment: you need en-us just en or English for the output ?

Comment: Thank you Gastón, the problem was languageCode must be set at *auth()* instead of *firebase* object.